# using imagesprit concept in html for combining 2 images in to single

Tags: html, css

**CSS :**

```
#notification{
    margin-left:41px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 78px;
    height: 38px;
    background: url("../images/notification1.png") 0 0 no-repeat;   
    cursor: pointer;
}

#notification:hover{
    background: url("../images/notification2.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="notification" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#notification-message"></div>
```

In this I am toggling two images during hover. For that I am trying to use image sprite technology, to reduce time and bandwidth, but it is not working. Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Have you looked at `background-position`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Comment: Look like you forget to join the `notification1.png` and `notification2.png` files. :D

Comment: iam loading bothimages seperately from server how to join both in to a single image

Comment: its hovering but taking few secs to load the next image during hover at that time that place become empty with out both images

Comment: The idea behind using an image sprite is to combine both images into one so that the image is only requested once. To change between images in the sprite, use background-position. To create the sprite, use an image editor.